# Clarification on putting a google calender entry from java

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am trying to put an entry in google calendar from my application. Just a simple text title, content and date entries. Please find below the code snippet which am trying to use;

```
    public void temp() {
        URL postURL = null;
        try {
            postURL = new URL("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/MAILID@gmail.com/PASSWORD/full");
            EventEntry eventEntry = new EventEntry();
            eventEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("One"));
            eventEntry.setContent(new PlainTextConstruct("Two"));

            When eventTime = new When();
            eventTime.setStartTime(DateTime.parseDateTime("2016-03-09T15:00:00-08:00"));
            eventTime.setEndTime(DateTime.parseDateTime("2016-03-09T15:00:00-08:00"));
            eventEntry.addTime(eventTime);

            CalendarService calendarService = new CalendarService("Savor");
            EventEntry createdEvent = calendarService.insert(postURL, eventEntry);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When executing this, am getting the service forbidden exception;
[Ignore the line numbers though]

```
    com.google.gdata.util.ServiceForbiddenException: Forbidden
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Forbidden</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Forbidden</H1>
<H2>Error 403</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:605)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.insert(Service.java:1409)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.insert(GoogleService.java:613)
    at GCalender.temp(GCalender.java:65)
    at GCalender.main(GCalender.java:88)


The exception is being thrown at this line: EventEntry createdEvent = CalendarService.insert(postURL, eventEntry);
```

Any one faced the same issue already? Kindly provide your inputs, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's back track your code.

In order for you to create a Calendar successfully, these are your checklist:

> - set your OAuth scope to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.
> - ensure the authenticated user has write access to the calendar with    the calendarId you provided (for example by calling calendarList.get()
>     for the calendarId and checking the accessRole).

Other things to check like enabling the API in developer console, oauth key can be viewed in this [guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth)(if you are not using service account to access the calendar). If you are using your a service account then go to this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).